# How to verify if a Windows network path I don't have access to is valid?

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, network-shares

One of my FTP jobs is failing to place a file in a Windows network directory.  I'm assuming the reason for this is a  change in the network path as it never had an issue in the past.

For example: `\\server\new folder` may have been changed to something like `\\server\newfolder` which could be the reason but I do not have access to confirm it.

How can I verify a Windows network path is valid when I don't have access to it?

Comment: If you do not have access to confirm it - your only method is to ask whoever manages the server and ask them the question if the folder have been moved, or if your access have been revoked. Or if you are not the only one that need to access that network folder - ask the other people if they have lost access or not. If they also have lost access - maybe issue / changes done at server side. If they have access and you don't - you lost access (somehow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way from a client computer to tell the difference between a share that:

- doesn't exist
- you aren't allowed to access
- is temporarily offline

The best solution is to contact the administrator of the server hosting the share and ask him.